# C++: Asynchronous writing memory

Tags: c++, performance, computation, asynchronous

I got few question about C++ programming. I would like to know if it's possible to write in memory in an asynchronous way (sequential code)? But let me be clear about my question.
I m looking for improvements for an algorithm and it seems that the bottleneck of my code is writing in memory. I would like to write in memory and still continue to compute. Is it possible to do so with one processor? Like using the ALU and the same time using the writing block? Knowing, I'm not using the result in the next computation. It's written in a vector result.

Thank you for taking time to respond, either reading.

Comment: Your bottleneck is not writing to memory. It's either loading the memory pages in a wrong way, or just a long synchronous loop that takes time just to go over the entire range.

Comment: Have you tried using fork?

Comment: If you're interested in how modern processors actually do this at a low level, I recommend picking up a computer architecture textbook, such as Hennesey and Patterson.  Modern processors are already very "out-of-order".

Comment: No I didn't try using Fork, I ll look at it and surely a textbook of computer architecture. Anyways thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Yochai Timmer. The algorithm take 35 ms with writing if I remove this instruction it takes 5 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. The compiler will optimize memory writes so that your processor can be doing things while blocks of memory are being written. This is a form of **latency hiding**. That's the "yes" answer.

The "no" part is that, unfortunately from a code standpoint, we cannot do this with a single thread.

Input/Output is the bottleneck in many, many programs, so it's just something you'll have to optimize and deal with.

Comment: I already use bypass cache intrinsic function to optimize the writing memory process but it's like I feel that I can do something more. But maybe it's just pure fantasy. Anyway thank you for your answer

Comment: @user3018144: You're welcome. We might be able to help more if you want to paste your code or algorithm. Also, the people at Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ live for code optimization, so you may want to post your code there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm gonna post it on the site.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question of C++ or whatever, it simply is a question of CPU support: C++ can't offer you such a facility, if the underlying hardware is not able to support it.

The x86 instruction provides has no such facility, but AFAIK the newer PPC versions do. If you want to go down the hardware route, you should first check what hardware you currently use: The memory latency is vastly different with different x86 CPUs.

Comment: I wanted to know if it was possible to do such things under C++. But Ok, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize memory writing.

1. Compress data that you write to save memory bandwidth.
2. Write locally - to one contiguous memory chunk to use processor's write buffer more efficiently.
3. Write it from one thread to prevent false sharing.
4. Maybe [__builtin_prefetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) can help here, but I don't know for sure.